# local folder in application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have added a folder to a project folder under Assets Named Images. Im trying to access the file, but i am not able to find the folder. Ive been using some code i found:

```
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var SharedFolder = await local.GetFolderAsync("Shared");
var ImagesFolder = await SharedFolder.GetFolderAsync("Images");
```

I always get an `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cant find the file specified`
Ive also tried just using this line alone

```
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var ImagesFolder = await local.GetFolderAsync("Images");
```

I still get this error. is there something i am missing?!

Comment: You have added isolatedstorage tag but you're talking about using a folder inside a project. Those are two different things. If you're not talking about isolatedstorage, I will remove that tag (or you can do it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets/Images");
```